# What is the error "App Terminating"?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsrangeexception

**Error**:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Here my **code**:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"AartiTableViewCell";
    AartiTableViewCell *cell = (AartiTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AartiTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.btnFav.userInteractionEnabled=YES;            
    }

    NSString *strfavarry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT  Title FROM %@ WHERE identifire='%@'",[FavTablename objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[FavIdent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    FavTitle = [FavData lookupAllForSQL:strfavarry];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.index = indexPath.row;
    cell.btnFav.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.btnFav setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unfav.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.btnFav addTarget:self action:@selector(handleFavouriteButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
    cell.lbltitle.text=[FavTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What part of the error do you have problem with? The debugger will show the exact place where the issue is.

Comment: due to index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

Comment: where to fill FavTablename and FavIdent array because this array may be less value of your numberofrows count.

Comment: What are you returning in `NumberOfRows` delegate method?

Comment: i m returning Favtablename  and in this array 12 element @pkc456

Comment: @seggy, Return `FavTitle.count`. You are dealing with `FavTitle` in cellForRow method not with `Favtablename `.

Comment: brow FavTitle have null value i add value in didselectrow thats why i can't return FavTitle.count @pkc456

Comment: @seggy, Implement exception handling as written [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39351949/988169)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSString *strfavarry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT  Title FROM %@ WHERE identifire='%@'",[FavTablename objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[FavIdent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

This line is given the error because your numberofrows count is greater than these array count value.

please check your numberofrows count and `FavTablename` and `FavIdent` array count is same or not.

Comment: yes i will check both array  same @Pooja Srivastava

Answer (score 0):

This error means you are trying to get an element from an array at index 1 and you are going out of bounds.

**Probably** the problem is:

```
[FavTablename objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

check if your array has some elements before reading from it.

To be sure of your problem enable the exception breakpoint:

[image]

Comment: in the tablename have 12 element

Comment: still not working @Marco Santarossa can i use this method out of 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' and i want all elements in FavTitle

Answer (score 0):

As you said that `FavTitle` and `Favtablename` have same number of elements. So try to put a exception handling in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as follows:-

```
if(FavTitle.count > indexPath.row){
        cell.lbltitle.text=[FavTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```